# Ways to restrict a device usage for enterprise applications

Tags: android, enterprise, android-device-manager

Our Android team is developing an Android application for finance company to manage their customers and business data with some back-end structure. The app is supposed to be used by company employees only and is not intended to be published to PlayStore either. Company wants to restrict employees access to android features and limit them to network connectivity, install app updates, restrict user to install other apps from Playstore and other similar things. I hope you understand what kind of restrictions a company would desire for its employees. Now I want to know, in what ways our team can create such system so that these requirements can be met?

Edit: Application is supposed to be used on tablets only and probably Samsung ones.

Comment: Well, I would go for a launcher based solution, you can create a custom launcher where u can hide specific apps.

Comment: But it does not seem secure as user can go to settings and uninstall the launcher app itself. I am looking for something more strong control over device activities may be through some device management APIs if available.

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look into this http://flyve-mdm.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- Go with an **MDM Provider** of your choice. They use APIs which can put the App in Kiosk mode
- Create your own MDM Solution. I feel documentation is lacking though and it's not an easy task Check out the documentation: https://www.android.com/enterprise/management/
  For some MDM Types you're still tied to the Google Play Store, I'm not quite sure if you're actually able to deploy apps without it.
- Use rooted devices and create a systemoverlay over the notification bar. You will not be able to access the settings that way but also not the notifications...